# Console application crashing

Tags: c#, .net, console, console-application

Hi guys i have here a console application written in c# ,
I have spend all my week finding and looking for the reason why it sometimes suddenly crashing,
this console app is running continuously, no closing means when i run it it will kept running no shutting down of computer

I put every method with try catch and every catch exception it will write it to the logs
but when the application crashed there's no logs  so that means there's exception that not being handled

can some one help find the possible reason why.
I'm drop off the whole code here.

```
 class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        protected static string server_hostname = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerHostname"];
        protected static string copychimp_server = "";
        protected static int port_number = 0;

        private static byte[] _buffer = new byte[10000];
        private static List<Socket> _clientSockets = new List<Socket>();
        private static Socket _serverSocket = new Socket(Dns.GetHostEntry(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerHostname"]).AddressList[0].AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        private static Dictionary<string, DateTime> dict_cmd_lastsent = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();

        private static Dictionary<string, double> dict_cmd_interval = new Dictionary<string, double>();

        private static Dictionary<string, string> dict_drive = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        private static Dictionary<string, string> dict_host = new Dictionary<string, string>();



        static bool ConsoleEventCallback(int eventType)
        {
            if (eventType == 2)
            {

            }
            return false;
        }
        static ConsoleEventDelegate handler;   // Keeps it from getting garbage collected
        // Pinvoke
        private delegate bool ConsoleEventDelegate(int eventType);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ConsoleEventDelegate callback, bool add);


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.Write(" Enter copychimp server: ");
            copychimp_server = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter port number: ");
            port_number = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            //copychimp_server = args[0].ToString().Trim();
            //port_number = Convert.ToInt16(args[1]);

            //Thread.Sleep(3000);
            try
            {

                var server_logs_dir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\logs\\" + copychimp_server;
                var server_config_dir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\config";
                var server_config = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\config\\" + copychimp_server + ".config";


                if (!Directory.Exists(server_config_dir))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(server_config_dir);

                }


                if (!Directory.Exists(server_logs_dir))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(server_logs_dir);


                }

                var config = "";
                config += "<port>" + port_number + "</port>";
                config += Environment.NewLine;

                try
                {

                    var pid = GetTagValue(File.ReadAllText(server_config), "PID");
                    var test_pid = Process.GetProcessById(Convert.ToInt16(pid));
                    var pname = test_pid.ProcessName;
                    ServerLogs(pname + " is currently active using PID (" + pid + ")");

                    config += "<PID>" + pid + "</PID>";
                    File.WriteAllText(server_config, config);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    config += "<PID>" + Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id + "</PID>";
                    File.WriteAllText(server_config, config);

                    handler = new ConsoleEventDelegate(ConsoleEventCallback);
                    const int SW_HIDE = 0;
                    var handle = GetConsoleWindow();


                    ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE); // To hide

                    ServerStarted();
                    Console.ReadKey();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ServerLogs("Main error: " + ex.Message.ToString());
            }


        }


        private static void ServerStarted()
        {
            try
            {
                IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(server_hostname);
                IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port_number);

                ServerLogs("CopyChimpServer.exe Started. Waiting for connection...");

                _serverSocket.Bind(localEndPoint);
                _serverSocket.Listen(1);
                _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);

            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                ServerLogs("ServerStarted Error " + ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }

        private static string ServerCommand(string hostname)
        {
            var command = "";
            try
            {
                CopyChimpDB copychimp_db = new CopyChimpDB();
                DataTable dt_robocopy = copychimp_db.GetCopyChimp("GetCommand", hostname, "");

                if (dt_robocopy.Rows.Count == 1)
                {
                    command = dt_robocopy.Rows[0]["command"].ToString();
                }
                else if (dt_robocopy.Rows.Count > 1)
                {
                    ServerLogs(hostname + " GetCommand error: Returns more than 1 row.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ServerLogs(hostname + " ServerCommand error " + ex.ToString());
            }
            return command;
        }



        private static void ReceiveCallBack(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Socket socket = null;
            string hostname = "";
            string ip_address = "";

            CopyChimpDB copychimp_db = new CopyChimpDB();
            try
            {
                socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
                int received = socket.EndReceive(AR);

                ip_address = (socket.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint).ToString().Split(':')[0];
                hostname = dict_host[ip_address];

                byte[] dataBuff = new byte[received];
                Array.Copy(_buffer, dataBuff, received);

                string message_to_client = "wait";

                if (Convert.ToDouble(Math.Round((DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(dict_cmd_lastsent[hostname])).TotalMinutes, 2)) >= dict_cmd_interval[hostname])
                {
                    var server_command = ServerCommand(hostname);

                    if (server_command.Trim() != "")
                    {
                        //string message_from_client = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuff));
                        message_to_client += "<DriveName>" + dict_drive[hostname] + "</DriveName>";
                        message_to_client += "<ServerCommand>" + ServerCommand(hostname) + "</ServerCommand>";

                        try
                        {
                            copychimp_db.PostCopyChimp("ConnectMachine", hostname, ip_address);
                        }
                        catch (Exception oraex)
                        {
                            ServerLogs(hostname + "--" + oraex.ToString());
                        }
                        dict_cmd_lastsent[hostname] = DateTime.Now;
                        //ServerLogs(hostname + " updated");
                    }


                }

                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message_to_client);
                socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), socket);
                socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), socket);
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                try
                {
                    //_clientSockets.Remove(socket);
                    ServerLogs(hostname + " SocketException! " + ex.Message.ToString());
                    if (hostname != "")
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            copychimp_db.PostCopyChimp("DisconnectMachine", hostname, ip_address);
                        }
                        catch (Exception oraex)
                        {
                            ServerLogs(hostname + "--" + oraex.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex_)
                {
                    ServerLogs(hostname + " DisconnectMachine error! " + ex_.ToString());
                }

            }
        }
        private static Thread thread;
        private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            string hostname = "";
            try
            {
                CopyChimpDB copychimp_db = new CopyChimpDB();
                Socket socket = _serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
                string ip_address = "";

                //hostname checking
                ip_address = (socket.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint).ToString().Split(':')[0];
                try
                {
                    try
                    {
                        hostname = Dns.GetHostEntry(ip_address).HostName;
                    }
                    catch (Exception host_ex)
                    {
                        ServerLogs(ip_address + " GetHostEntry error: " + host_ex.Message.ToString());
                        DataTable dt_ip = copychimp_db.GetCopyChimp("GetHostnameByIpAddress", hostname, ip_address);
                        if (dt_ip.Rows.Count == 1)
                        {
                            hostname = dt_ip.Rows[0]["hostname"].ToString();
                            ServerLogs(ip_address + " GetHostnameByIpAddress : " + hostname);

                        }
                    }
                    DataTable dt_hostname = copychimp_db.GetCopyChimp("GetHostname", hostname, ip_address);
                    hostname = "";
                    if (dt_hostname.Rows.Count == 1)
                    {
                        hostname = dt_hostname.Rows[0]["hostname"].ToString();
                    }
                    else if (dt_hostname.Rows.Count > 1)
                    {
                        ServerLogs(hostname + " GetHostname error: Returns more than 1 row.");
                    }

                    if (hostname != "")
                    {

                        if (!_clientSockets.Contains(socket))
                        {
                            dict_host[ip_address] = hostname;
                            _clientSockets.Add(socket);

                            copychimp_db.PostCopyChimp("ConnectMachine", hostname, ip_address);
                            /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
                            dict_cmd_interval[hostname] = Convert.ToDouble(copychimp_db.GetCopyChimp("GetInterval", hostname, ip_address).Rows[0]["interval"].ToString());
                            /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
                            dict_cmd_lastsent[hostname] = Convert.ToDateTime(copychimp_db.GetCopyChimp("GetLastUpdate", hostname, ip_address).Rows[0]["lastupdate"]);
                            /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
                            dict_drive[hostname] = copychimp_db.GetCopyChimp("GetDriveName", hostname, ip_address).Rows[0]["drive_name"].ToString();
                            /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
                            thread = new Thread(() =>
                            {
                                socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), socket);
                            });
                            thread.Start();

                            ServerLogs(hostname + " connected");
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception oraex)
                {
                    ServerLogs(hostname + "--" + oraex.ToString());
                }
                _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                ServerLogs("AcceptCallback SocketException " + hostname + ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }

        private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            socket.EndSend(AR);
        }

        private static void ServerLogs(string text)
        {
            bool logging_success = false;
            try
            {
                string logpath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\logs\\" + copychimp_server + "\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".log";
                do
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string log = "[" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "]" + "  " + text + Environment.NewLine;

                        if (!File.Exists(logpath))
                        {
                            File.WriteAllText(logpath, log);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            File.AppendAllText(logpath, log);
                        }
                        logging_success = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                    }
                } while (logging_success == false);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //send emai
            }
        }

        private static string GetTagValue(string text, string tag)
        {
            var result = "";
            try
            {
                var start_tag = "<" + tag + ">";
                var end_tag = "</" + tag + ">";
                int pFrom = text.IndexOf(start_tag) + start_tag.Length;
                int pTo = text.LastIndexOf(end_tag);
                result = text.Substring(pFrom, pTo - pFrom);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ServerLogs("GetTagValue() error " + ex.Message.ToString());

            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

A help a highly appreciated thank you in advance.
 I need to log it on the DB before the crushing occurred and i'm going to use it as reference for a new automatic emailing if the app crashed.

Comment: Why do you call `socket.BeginReceive` in a new thread? It's already an asynchronous method. As it stats in the docs: _"**This method does not block** until the operation is complete. To block until the operation is complete, use one of the Receive method overloads."_

Comment: My first guess is that its trying to write multiple ServerLogs at the same time as that doesnt write out an error if it cant.

Comment: Anything in the EventLog?

Comment: there's something in the logs , but it's not error log, it's process log, i need to log it on the DB before the crushing occured and i'm going to use it as reference for a new automatic email

Comment: You could prevent the app from closing by adding `Console.ReadKey()` in your try block of the Main method of your console app code.

Comment: i don'y think it would help the application needed to keep on running 24/7 and sometimes in mid night i need to press a key to continue the process

Comment: There is too much code here, please read [ask]

Comment: @ BugFinder if it is the reason, would the app crashed?, i think it will still be able to run after error on writing the logs,